# Filtering and counting groups with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"car":["mazda", "mazda", "audi", "bmw", "audi"], "cost":[10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 45000]})
```

and how can I print table which will show me 3 columns:

1. Name of car
2. Cost of car, but I want to see only cars which cost is between 20000 and 45000
3. number of cars of a given brand

SO I need to have something like this:

```
1.  audi   20000   2
2.  bmw    30000   1
3.  audi   45000   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first filter the cars with:

```
data = data[data['cost'].between(20000, 45000)]
```

We can make use of **`.transform(..)`** here to calculate the number of cars (`'count'`) per `car` type:

```
data['count'] = data.groupby('car').transform('count')
```

This then yields:

```
>>> data
     car   cost
0  mazda  10000
1  mazda  15000
2   audi  20000
3    bmw  30000
4   audi  45000
>>> data = data[data['cost'].between(20000, 45000)]
>>> data['count'] = data.groupby('car').transform('count')
>>> data
    car   cost  count
2  audi  20000      2
3   bmw  30000      1
4  audi  45000      2
```

Answer (score 2):

For questions 1 and 2:

```
df = data.query('cost>=20000 & cost<=45000')
df
# returns:
    car   cost
2  audi  20000
3   bmw  30000
4  audi  45000
```

For question 3:

```
df.merge(data.groupby('car').count().rename(
    columns={'cost': 'count'}), left_on='car', right_index=True)
# returns:
    car   cost  count
2  audi  20000      2
4  audi  45000      2
3   bmw  30000      1
```